# Transliteration google api required

Tags: transliteration

I need a Google transliteration for python or any other language. Is there any Google api available to achiving the task or any other solution available for transliteration through programming ?

Comment: Do you need to transliterate from informal "hinglish" / "arabizi" / translit into the proper Hindi, Arabic, Russian Cyrillic etc?  Or do you simply need to transcribe proper Hindi, Arabic, Russian etc into Latin chars?

Comment: @AdamM.B., I want to transliterate from Roman(English) script to Devanagari (Hindi/Sanskrit) Script.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4 you have the Transliterator class, it's working very well for me.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php